# How do I submit an HTML form using formsubmit.co without redirection of the page?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I have been trying to make a form in HTML (Bootstrap) that sends the information to my mail id. for this I am using [formsubmit](https://formsubmit.co/).

for some reason, when submiting the form, It redirects the page to a 'success' page. I do realise that there is a way to redirect it to a different page but I would rather have the section in which the form is present to disappear and show a 'success' section. For reference, here is my form code:

```html
<section id="get-started" class="get-started">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row text-center">
      <h1 class="display-3 fw-bold text-capitalize">Get started</h1>
      <div class="heading-line"></div>
      <!-- <p class="lh-lg">
        can write something here later
      </p> -->
    </div>

    <!-- START THE CTA CONTENT  -->
    <div class="row text-white">
      <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 gradient shadow p-3">
        <div class="cta-info w-100">
          <h4 class="display-4 fw-bold">Sign up for Beta!</h4>
          <p class="lh-lg">
            Join the waitlist for the beta program. Limited spots available!         </p>
          <h3 class="display-3--brief">What will be the next step?</h3>
          <ul class="cta-info__list">
            <li>Enter your details.</li>
            <li>Wait to be accepted into the beta program.</li>
            <li>Enjoy using Clickytize.</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 bg-white shadow p-3">
        <div class="form w-100 pb-2">
          <h4 class="display-3--title mb-5">Join the waitlist!</h4>
          <form action="https://formsubmit.co/533cb72c9e26d2503a81229e9c8a246a" method="POST" class="row">
            <input type="hidden" name="_captcha" value="false">

            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md mb-3">
              <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" id="inputFirstName" name="firstName" class="shadow form-control form-control-lg">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md mb-3">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" id="inputLastName" name="lastName" class="shadow form-control form-control-lg">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12 mb-3">
              <input type="email" placeholder="email address" id="inputEmail" name="emailId" class="shadow form-control form-control-lg">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12 mb-3">
              <textarea name="message" placeholder="Link your social media profile" id="message" name="message" class="shadow form-control form-control-lg"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="text-center d-grid mt-1">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary rounded-pill pt-3 pb-3">
                submit
                <i class="fas fa-paper-plane"></i>
              </button>

              <script>
                form.onSubmit= (event)=>{
                  event.preventDefault();
                }

              </script>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to prevent redirection of page and submit the form  then you need to take care of submitting the form data using javascript.

First add `onsubmit` event attribute in your `form` tag like this:

```
<form  method="POST" class="row my-form" onsubmit="return submitForm()">
```

We can remove the `action` attribute from the `form` tag.

in Javascript:

```
function submitForm() {
        
        const form = document.querySelector('.my-form')
        const formData = new FormData(form)
        const url = 'https://formsubmit.co/533cb72c9e26d2503a81229e9c8a246a'
        fetch(
          url,
          {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData
          }
        )
        return false
    }
```

We are using the native `fetch` API  to send data to form-data to the endpoint. We are also using the `FormData` API  to create an object of form `inputs`

Returing `false` prevents page from reload.

Read more about:
[Fetch API](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi-ov2KqffyAhXlQ3wKHTbCAD4QFnoECAcQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.geeksforgeeks.org%2Fjavascript-fetch-method%2F&usg=AOvVaw1uNjOyMkTcLcu2kO0Nu5yJ) [FormData API](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiAj_amqffyAhUa4XMBHVGXDOAQFnoECBsQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fjavascript.info%2Fformdata&usg=AOvVaw3BX7ufG1BT0Z1TkieETPOA)